# Should I be permissive of unknown parameters?

Tags: rest, api-design

I'm designing a RESTful API and faced with the title problem, restated for clarity:

Should I fail fast if a client sends an unrecognized parameter? For example,

```
http://example.com/api/foo?bar=true&paula=bean
```

In the above, `bar` is a valid parameter but `paula` is not specified by the API. Should I

- Warn the client of the error
- Fail fast
- Ignore it

If I warn the client, I can only issue a warning for the first parameter, since they could be sending a near-infinite number of them, and the server presumably has better things to do. Similarly, when failing, it would only specify the first invalid param as the problem.

I prefer failure over issuing a warning to force the programmer to take action, as they might otherwise ignore the problem and keep wasting resources, or end up cargo-culting themselves inadvertently. Doing nothing is even worse in that respect.

Do my arguments make sense? Is there an accepted practice on such things?

Comment: Based on a small test, all sites that I tested simply ignore the unknown parameters that I supplied them.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Same here. It's fine for web pages but I don't think it's ok for an actual API

Comment: A concern is forward compatibility. If unknown arguments are ignored it is possible to use them in future versions in such a way that clients can program to the new API and still get reasonable behavior on old servers.

Comment: @walpen That's an interesting point. Using versioned URLs `api/v1` etc. would take care of that, but it still doesn't allow for incremental updates. +1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In my opinion, you should return an Invalid Request status, so that the client knows that what it's trying to do isn't valid. My opinion on this is influenced by the concept that RESTful APIs are *discoverable*. If you're providing sufficient information up front, then the client never tries to make an invalid request to begin with. If it does, then there's something wrong in the client code and failing fast will alert the second to this bug. Of course, that's a very purist approach and may not be recommended if your API isn't discoverable.

A more pragmatic approach may be to ignore the invalid params, but either way you go, be sure to document the behavior well.

Comment: As an extension: if a client send some unknown/readonly/deprecated parameters, that means, that the client expects some behavior which will not be fulfilled. And therefore it is dangerous to perform any action. So I agree, strictly Bad Request

Comment: Thanks @StepanStepanov, but there is the "Be permissive in what you accept, explicit about what you send out" philosophy underlying much of the web's architecture. With that in mind, I could easily write an answer in direct opposition to the one I already wrote.

Comment: I've googled this )) And the page about Postel's law says also "code that receives input should accept non-conformant input as long as the meaning is clear". I think, if client send us some unknown parameter, its meaning cannot be clear. If client sends us a deprecated parameter it is clear, it will not work as before and as client expects. If client send us a read-only parameter it is clear, it will be not written as client wants.

Comment: Postel disagrees.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle

Comment: I disagree with this. One example of an arbitrarily added parameter that should not be blocked is a **cache-buster**. Your proposed solution would effectively make it impossible for frontends to avoid browser or network caching issues (which are beyond your api's control) - or you're signing yourself up for your api having to explicitly allow for this by defining a specific query parameter that you allow which consumers then need to be informed about.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just warn them but still allow unknown query parameters.

Remember, sometimes it's going to be *you* who will deprecate query parameters. I don't think your clients would appreciate it if you decide to change how an endpoint works, breaking their code in the process. Accepting useless input is something you have to tolerate as a trade off for forward compatibility.

Versioning your API is the correct way of deprecating query parameters, because a version change is the moment when your clients will go through your documentation again and rebuild their request payloads.

I think it'd be unmanageable if every incremental update risks breaking your API.

Comment: If possible, the reply could document exactly which parameters were used.  So, if caller requested    `?bar=true&paula=bean` and paula is invalid, it could return (here I;m using JSON) something like `requestParameters: { bar: true }`

Answer (score 1):

If you do public API (or api that will be used by other team), I would recommend return error as @RubberDuck suggested.

If your api will be consumed only inside your team (or only by yourself), it maybe easier to ignore extra fields (e.g. requires less code and easier to do).